# Seeking step-by-step instructions to install an old version of TeX Live

Tags: texlive, installing

The [TeX Live availability](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) page states that installing old versions of TeX Live can be done, and different versions on the same system will not conflict. It provides a link to the [historic archive](https://www.tug.org/historic/), but no instructions for how to do the installation.

The [Quick install for Unix](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) page provides step-by-step instructions, but they do not work when installing older versions. The `./install.tl` perl script complains that the repository is of a different version than the script, like so:

```
./install-tl: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2021
 repository: 2023
```

Answer (score 3):

### Steps

To install the 2021 version of Tex Live on a Unix system, run the following commands. For releases from other years, simply replace `2021` with the desired year.

```
cd /tmp                                  # or some other working directory
wget https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
zcat < install-tl-unx.tar.gz | tar xf -  # See below about the tar archive name
cd install-tl-20220322/                  # Replace with the directory that zcat/tar actually produced
sudo mkdir /usr/local/texlive
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/texlive      # See below regarding root or group ownership
./install-tl -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final
```

Finally, prepend `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` (replacing the
year and platform as appropriate) to your PATH. You can have multiple versions installed with no problem because each is located entirely within a separate subdirectory: `/usr/local/texlive/2020/`, `/usr/local/texlive/2021/`, etc. To switch from one version to another, just change your PATH.

### Notes

In the `wget` command, `https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic` is the URL of the mirror for the United States. You should replace it with another mirror if you are downloading TeX Live elsewhere in the world. Other mirrors are shown on the [Historic archive](https://www.tug.org/historic/) page.

If you've been installing multiple versions and have already downloaded another version, then `wget` may append a number to the name of the tar archive, giving you something like `install-tl-unx.tar.gz.2`. Be sure to use this name in the `zcat` line.

In the directory whose name is of the form `install-tl-*`, the `*` is the date of the last release of TeX Live of the year in question. Usually this date will
be early in the following year.

You do not need to be root to run `./install-tl` nor does TeX Live need to be owned by root. You only need a [writable directory](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html#running) to install to. By default, `./install-tl` installs to `/usr/local`. Best is to create a group for TeX Live admins, run `chgrp` to change the group of `/usr/local/texlive`, add user(s) to the group, and run `./install-tl` as one of the users of that group.

`./install-tl` is a perl script. The original instructions from TUG called `perl` explicitly to run it. If the last command above doesn't work, try this instead:

```
perl ./install-tl -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final
```

Comment: Is there some generic mirror one can use rather than connecting to `ftp.math.utah.edu`?

Comment: @Werner As far as I can tell, there is no generic mirror. I'll edit the answer right now, though, to include a link to the page listing all the mirrors.

Comment: Why are you calling `perl`? The install script can be run without that (and on Windows for example it would fail).

Comment: @JosephWright only because the instructions on the [Quick install](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) page include `perl` explicitly. I was wondering about that.

Comment: I would not use `sudo` but a [writable destination](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html#running). Doing everything using `sudo` IMHO is not the very best idea.

Comment: @cabohah A writable destination instead of `sudo` does sound better. I couldn't tell, though, how to set this up. `./install-tl` installs into `/usr/local` by default. `./install-tl --help` doesn't show a command-line option to specify the installation directory; it just prints out the perl script. Also, I couldn't tell what is a standard directory to put TeX Live in if not `/usr/local`. To keep the instructions very simple ("just do this"), what do you recommend?

Comment: `install-tl` installs to `/usr/local/texlive`. So you just need  `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive` and then either something like `sudo chown $USER /usr/local/texlive` or (IMHO better) generate a group for TeX Live admins, change the group of `/usr/local/texlive` add user(s) to that group and do installation with one of the users of the group.

Comment: Thanks, @cabohah. I just updated the answer. I'm wary of posting something other than commands that I actually ran myself. Will you please give the answer another close look to be sure the update is correct?

Comment: `$USER` should already be the user name of the current user without the need to replace it, because it is used in the context of the user running `sudo` not the `sudo` context (try, e.g., `sudo -- sh -c "echo $USER"` to see this and note, that it differs from `sudo -- sh -c 'echo $USER'`, which would show the name of root).

Comment: @cabohah Thanks! I've been using Un*x for decades and never knew this. I'll update it right now.